# Using input field box to change what rest service to call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with switching rest service call depending on what I enter input a input-box.

Upon loading the page the first time, it should `GET 1.xml`
If I enter 2 in the box, it should reload the page with `xmlhttp.open("GET" 2.xml,false)`

```
$('#button').click(function(){
        var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", userInput+".xml",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
        location.reload();
});
```

After reloading, the userInput gets reset and the page still calls 1.xml instead of whatever I entered. How to fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need to reload the page?

Comment: display the page with new information from the new XML according to what I entered

Comment: @jennyC : You have used wrong variable to pass as `.xml` and there lies your problem. See my answer..

Comment: Ok but after I reload it, the variable gets wiped anyways

Comment: Why don't you just update the DOM / innerHTML of an element with the new content instead of reloading the page?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong usage of variable. See the updated code :

```
$('#button').click(function(){
        var inputVal = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", inputVal +".xml",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
        location.reload();
});
```

What you did was to get user input value in a variable `input` like :

```
var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
```

But you are using another variable `userInput` which would have no value as the page to be posted.

```
    xmlhttp.open("GET", userInput+".xml",false);
```